# sicp 2.4.3 data directed programming and additivity, scheme

Tags: scheme

Could some provide clarification to the example of complex arithmetic decribed in [the chapter](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-17.html#%25_sec_2.4.3). I can not understand one point. I would appreciate any help.
The problem is the following:

There are two packages with similiar naming of procedures.
The first one is "(install-rectangular-package)". The second one is "(install-polar-package)". In addition, a procedure is defined:
(define (make-from-real-imag x y)
    (get 'make-from-real-imag 'rectangular) x y))

i type in scheme interperter 
(install-rectangular-package)
(install-polar-package)
(make-from-real-imag 3 5)

and it works. what i do not understand how "get" inside "make-from-real" finds proper function in the proper package. when the string "(get 'make-from-real-imag 'rectangular)" is executed ,it replaces by "(lambda (x y) (tag (make-from-real-imag x y))))" but how it knows that it has to call function inside "(install-rectangular-package)" but not in "(install-polar-package)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [chapter](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-17.html#%25_sec_2.4.3) includes [some sentences](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-17.html#%_idx_2438) that say you are simply supposed to *assume* that the procedures `put` and `get` exist:

> To implement this plan, assume that we have two procedures, `put` and `get`, for manipulating the operation-and-type table:
>
> ```
> (put <op> <type> <item>)
> ```
>
> installs the `<item>` in the table, indexed by the `<op>` and the `<type>`.
>
> ```
> (get <op> <type>)
> ```
>
> looks up the `<op>`, `<type>` entry in the table and returns the item found there. If no item is found, `get` returns false.
>
> For now, we can assume that `put` and `get` are included in our language.

So, now we must ask for a clarification of your question:

1. Are you asking "how can implement a procedure like `install-rectangular-package` so that after `(install-rectangular-package)` is evaluated, the `get` procedure can lookup the desired operations?"
2. Or are you asking "how does `get` itself *work*?"
3. Or are you asking: "Even *if* we assume such a table for supporting `put` and `get` exists, how can the [presented code](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-17.html#%_idx_2448) work, where it installs multiple distinct functions with names like `real-part` (and `imag-part`,  etc) even though the one `real-part` comes from the rectangular package, and another `real-part` comes from the polar package?"

---

If you are asking the first question, the answer is: `install-rectangular-package` simply calls `put` with the appropriate arguments to extend the lookup table that `get` will access.

---

If you are asking the second question, then you will need to see how `put` and `get` are implemented, which is discussed in Chapter 3. But the quick answer is: You could use a data structure that stores a record of every `{<op>, <type>, <item>}` triple inserted by `put`. The book describes one way to do this, where you just build up a list of entries.

(The main interesting thing that any implementation of `put` and `get` needs to do is imperatively modify some hidden state. The book uses the `set-cdr!` operation to do this. The requirement to use some form of imperative operation is probably the reason why they waited until Chapter 3 to describe the implementation of `put` and `get`.)

---

If you are asking the third question, the answer is "by the magic of [lexical scoping](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_idx_620)"

The definition of `install-rectangular-package` has a collection of internal definitions, and `install-polar-package` has another collection of internal definitions. Even though there is overlap between the names chosen in the two definitions, installing the polar package does *not* overwrite the functions previously defined by the rectangular package.

(It is important to distinguish here between the name used in a function definition versus the function value/object (which you might think of as the `(lambda (x y) ...)`) itself. Even though `install-rectangular-package` and `install-polar-package` reuse the same names, they are creating distinct function values, and those distinct values are then being put into the `put`/`get` table, *without* any significance attached to the name used to originally define them.)

Even though the picture of the `put`/`get` table in the book looks like:

[image: Table of Operations for complex number system]

the entries in the table are *not* names. They are instead function objects. Other local definitions of `real-part` or `imag-part` will not affect the entries that were installed by `install-rectangular-package` nor `install-polar-package`; the only way to affect those entries is to *call* `put` itself with the matching `<op>` and `<type>` arguments to overwrite the previous cell in the table.

For more discussion of lexical scope and ways to think about local function definitions, I recommend [this part of HtDP](http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-23.html#node_chap_18) ("HtDP" stands for "How to Design Programs", which, like SICP, is an intro to programming, but written in a fashion that spells things out a bit more than SICP does; see also this [paper comparing SICP and HtDP](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/racket/pubs/jfp2004-fffk.pdf).)

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: But the question is different. it is not related neither to the first question nor the second. The question is when string "(lambda (x y) (tag (make-from-real-imag x y))))" is executed with some given values (like x=5 and y=3 ), how it can be that the proper function in the proper module is executed. In other words what mechanism lets to find and execute right function (there two with same name but in differents packages).

Comment: Ah, I see you were indeed asking a third question. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped. Please, let me ask a side question. if this book is intro in programming, could you tell, for example, which one is advanced (or intermediary) programming book. I would like to look it through for content, because SICP is kind of not easy reading and maybe I should not continue to read it.

Comment: HTDP is a much simpler (though slow) presentation than SICP. I love SICP but I only really appreciated its content after I had already learned what it was attempting to teach. I would recommend you give HTDP a try, since they are both freely available. The only problem with HTDP is that it can be a bit dry reading at times. It's possible the next edition addresses this: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/

Comment: Also if you work on the exercises in HtDP, that means you'll get to work in the DrRacket programmming environment, which is much much better for beginners (especially if you make use of the Lamguage Levels which will catch a number of beginner mistakes by keeping you within restricted subsets of the programming language that are more amenable to static analysis.)

Comment: thank you very much for help. I would like to ask if you could you recommend some book on advanced programming. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Uh, it depends on what kind of programming you are interested in doing.

Comment: Personally, looking quickly at my own bookshelf, I'm a fan of: 1. Knuths "The Art of Computer Programming" (particularly volume 4A). 2. "The Dragon book" Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools by Aho Lam Sethi and Ullman. 3. Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment by W. Richard Stevens ...